# Miniature Schnauzer Thicker hair grow after skin problems

Tags: dogs, allergies, skin-condition

I have an 11 year old miniature schnauzer, and around 4-ish years ago she developed skin allergies in her "lower-back" close to the tail, and she wouldn't stop scratching until the point of hurting herself (we assume these uncontrollable and hardcore scratching "spams" where due to the fact that she has a pedigree, and as I understand the purer the dog the more intense the *"faults/defects"* of the breed are present.

Eventually she lost most if not all of her hair in that area, and thankfully we've been able to control her allergies through:

- diet changing (food and water);
- baths with distilled water and hypoallergenic soaps;
- dressing her (she has less itching with them on) from time to time, but not
  all the time (humidity being a factor for all the bacteria to develop
  and whatnot);
- allergy medications (when really needed).

She still scratches herself from time to time but the itching is greatly decreased by now, she's finally growing hair again, the issue is that the hair now is much more thicker than her *original* hair. I was wondering if it has to do with all the lesions she caused herself that the skin got so heavily damaged beyond repair. Or if there's anything we can do about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had sometime over the weekend to do my own research; and found out some very possible reasons for which this thick hair is growing where the bald patches used to be.

First of all I would like to point out that schnauzers in general are very healthy dogs, although the miniature branch of the breed seems prone to skin problems, from [**Max The Schnauzer**](http://www.max-the-schnauzer.com/schnauzer-skin.html):

> ***While the majority of Schnauzers will have no problems at all, some do suffer from sensitive skin or allergies, often causing them to scratch, bite or lick themselves excessively.***

After visiting several schnauzer related forums, I found a pattern; after a schnauzer loses its hair (due to whatever reason) the new coat seems to be more thick/wirey than the fluffier coat on the rest of its body. This wirey coat turns out to be the dogs natural-ungroomed coat, from [**GoSchnauzer**](http://goschnauzer.com/bald-spots-on-mini-schnauzers-back/):

> ***Schnauzers naturally have a wirey coat that gets “destroyed” with grooming with clippers. A show schnauzer has its coat manually “stripped” – which involves taking the soft undercoat out and encouraging the growth of the wirey coat. These dogs will have a wirey flat coated back***

So when the Schnauzer's hair grows back it'll grow wirey and thick since this is how the natural coat is, it'll take several grooming sessions for the dog to have an even coat again.